# Offensive flag, disputed after edit. Will it appear negative on my profile?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive, disputed-flags

Today on Stack Overflow I came across a question which was, I don't know why, filled with profanity in comments and logs. There were so many instances of those foul words that it discouraged me to involve any of my little programming knowledge that I have in answering the question.

I flagged the question **Offensive** in full awareness of the severity of the flag. The flag was deemed helpful. Then somebody more sensible then me edited the question and changed the foul words to "censored". My flag was disputed.

I understand that flags are to draw moderators' attention and should be used with care and sense of responsibility. My question is: does a disputed flag affect my profile in a negative way in front of SO members and moderators?

**Edit:** I understand the literal effect of a disputed flag. It means flag was neither helpful nor declined. But it does imply that I blamed some body of very serious mistake and my blame did not stand other moderators' scrutiny. All I wanted to know was: Is the presence of disputed flag is frowned upon by members and moderators?

Comment: Is this the post in question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114502/if-statement-seems-to-be-forgetting-to-exist

Comment: @gnat I went through it but it does not talk about effect on my profile...for example you are not guilty after serving term but people are still suspicious of you kind of scenario...

Comment: as far as I can tell, answer in dupe directly addresses your question: "Disputed flags are considered neither helpful nor declined, regardless of the action taken in response to them."

Comment: [Yes, now you have to eat worms.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/An1s1.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not too much. Disputed/declined flags are visible on your profile to moderators, but they're not considered a big black mark.

As long as you don't consistently get a lot of declined/disputed flags, you're fine.